# mvc6: specify custom location for views of viewComponents

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

By default mvc6 searches for views of ViewComponents either in `/Views/ControllerUsingVc/Components` or it also looks in `/views/shared` folder.
Is it possible to add a custom location where it should look for them? E.g. `/views/mySharedComponents`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do that but you have to do following steps for that.

1. Create New View engine based on RazorViewEngine. Also by default it need Components directory so just use Views as root folder.

   ```
   namespace WebApplication10
   {
   public class MyViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
       {
           public MyViewEngine(IRazorPageFactory pageFactory, IViewLocationExpanderProvider viewLocationExpanderProvider, IViewLocationCache viewLocationCache) : base(pageFactory,viewLocationExpanderProvider,viewLocationCache)
           {

           }        
           public override IEnumerable<string> ViewLocationFormats
           {
               get
               {
                   List<string> existing = base.ViewLocationFormats.ToList();
                   existing.Add("/Views/{0}.cshtml");
                   return existing;                
               }
           }

       }
   ```

   }
2. Add ViewEngine in MVC in Startup.cs

   ```
   services.AddMvc().Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
           {              
               options.ViewEngines.Add(Type.GetType("WebApplication10.MyViewEngine"));             

           });
   ```
3. Now I have placed My Component at following location. For example my component name is MyFirst.cshtml. So I can place Views/Components/MyFirst/Default.cshtml.

Comment: the ViewEngines.Add method requires IViewEngine instance and not System.Type?

Answer (score 2):

Basically you can do this with creating custom view engine or creating custom [IViewLocationExpander](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Razor/IViewLocationExpander.cs)

But for view components in beta-6 there will be always "Components" prefix added. Look at [ViewViewComponentResult](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/e985fa5d423968f36a651a354d9c953192c52532/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ViewFeatures/ViewComponents/ViewViewComponentResult.cs) source code. And it is sad.

Good news you could create your own view component result by copying code above and replacing only formatting string for view searching.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's an old question, but it can be done much simpler...

```
services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(o =>
{
     o.ViewLocationFormats.Add("/views/{0}.cshtml");
});
```

Comment: This will result in `/views/Components/ComponentName/ViewName.cshtml`, since the `/Components/ComponentName/ViewName` is hard coded inside the [`ViewViewComponentResult` class](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/e985fa5d423968f36a651a354d9c953192c52532/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ViewFeatures/ViewComponents/ViewViewComponentResult.cs#L20).

Answer (score 0):

You can also do the following for **.NET Core**

```
services
    .AddMvc(options =>
    {
        ...
    })
    .AddRazorOptions(o =>
    {
        o.AreaViewLocationFormats.Add("Areas/{2}/Views/SUBFOLDER/{1}/{0}.cshtml");
        o.ViewLocationFormats.Add("Views/SUBFOLDER/{1}/{0}.cshtml");
    })
```

Obviously choose `AreaViewLocationFormats` or `ViewLocationFormats` based on whether you're using Areas or not.

Comment: Since view components have `/Components/ComponentName/ViewName` hard coded as the string formatted into `{0}`, this won't help.